# CodeMagic Automatic build is not triggered though it receives the webhook from github

Tags: codemagic

Automatic build is not triggered though it receives the webhook from github. Any input would be helpful.

**codemagic.yml snippet**

```
ionic-capacitor-android-app-qa:
    name: tulip-fp
    environment:
      node: latest
    triggering:
      events:
        - tag
      branch_patterns:
        - pattern: “uat”
          include: true
          source: true
      tag_patterns:
        - pattern: “*”
          include: true
....
```

**Recent deliveries:**
[image]

Comment: I have worked with #codemagic and here is the solutions -
1> Change "uat" to 'uat'. Basically use single quote in the pattern 
2> Also make sure in the webohook configuration in github, "push" trigger is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with #codemagic and here is the solutions -

1. Change "uat" to 'uat'. Basically use single quote in the pattern
2. Also make sure in the WebHook configuration in GitHub, "push" trigger is checked.

```
ionic-capacitor-android-app-qa:
    name: tulip-fp
    environment:
      node: latest
    triggering:
      events:
        - tag
        - push
      branch_patterns:
        - pattern: 'uat'
          include: true
          source: true
      tag_patterns:
        - pattern: '*'
          include: true
```